# Check if the child is the only content of the parent using jQuery

Tags: jquery, parent-child, href

I need to check if a link (a-tag) is the **only content** (not just the only child) inside a paragraph tag (p). So if the p-tag looks like this:

```
<p>Here we have some text inside the p-tag. Then there's <a href="#">link</a>.</p>
```

the `<a>` tag is not the only content inside the p-tag since there's also text.

But if the `<p>` tag looks like this:

```
<p><a href="#">Nothing but a link inside this p-tag</a></p>
```

the only content inside the `<p>` tag is the link.

If a `<p>` tag only contains an `<a>` tag I want to add a certain class to the `<a>` tag.

I was using this code:

```
$("#MainColumn p a:only-child").addClass("singleLink");
```

but this code only checks if the a-tag is the only child of the p-tag, not if it's the only **content**. This is where I'm currently stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It can be very easy with one selector:**

```
var $content = $("#MainColumn p:has(a)").filter(function() {
    return $(this).contents().length === 1;
}).children('a').addClass("singleLink");
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GeJkU/363/)

Comment: How about this:
$("#MainColumn p:has(a:only-child)").filter(function () {
    return $(this).contents().length === 1;
}).children('a').addClass('singleLink');

It seems to work when I run it on the acual page. I'm just not sure if it's the most efficient solution?

Comment: @tkahn. Mine is better... `:)` why do you want to change it?

Comment: I was just thinking that if I look for p-tags that only have a single child element that is an a-tag I would reduce the number of elements that are affected by the selector and thus reduce the number of elements that are filtered. But perhaps the :only-child pseudo selector in itself is resource hungry(?)

Comment: @tkahn. The difference is **negligible**, if you use that inside of  a big loop, then check it at jsperf, otherwise, I would just choose one, yours if fine also.

Comment: Thanks! As you've seen I'll go with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
  $('#MainColumn p a').each(function(){
    var p = $(this).parent().text().length;
    var s = $(this).text().length;
    if (p == s) {
        $(this).addClass('singleLink')
    }
  })
```

http://jsbin.com/ewoqoy/2/

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be what you are excepting

```
String.prototype.startsWith = function(prefix) {
    return this.indexOf(prefix) === 0;
}

String.prototype.endsWith = function(suffix) {
    return this.match(suffix+"$") == suffix;
};

var html = $("#myP").html();
if($("#myP p:only-child")){
if(html.startsWith("<p>") && html.endsWith("</p>")){
alert("hi");
}
}

<div id="myP"><p >Sample Text inside a <b>p</b> element</p></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Hmm...maybe you could check if the content starts with "http://" or "www":

```
if($("#MainColumn p a:only-child").text().indexOf("www") != -1 {


}
```

Because your link is also "content" you could not differ between "your content" and "no content". You have to say how "your content" is defined.

Comment: Nope - this is not what I'm looking for. I don't really care what's inside the a-tag.